# Dual boot - Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on "started bpfilter" while booting

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, bpfilter

I have on my computer Windows 10 and Ubuntu (18.04 if I'm not wrong) in dual boot with Grub. My GPU is a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960M. I have a problem that occurs often but not always :

When I boot on Ubuntu, my screen stays blocked with written "Started bpfilter" or "Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service". Sometimes it finishes and go to the main GUI, sometimes not even after hours.

I noticed that when I don't use my computer some hours and let it plugged off, this problem doesn't appear anymore for a certain period / number of boots.

I think the problem is due to the Nvidia drivers or the GPU in general and would like to try the solutions proposed here : https://www.mvps.net/docs/how-to-fix-the-boot-error-stuck-at-starting-bpfilter-on-ubuntu-19-04/

But can I test them on a dual boot computer without risk of damaging the Windows 10 installation, notably when removing Nvidia proprietary drivers or installing Slim ?

What would you recommend to do please ? Do you have another solution which could fix that ?

Thank you in advance for your help.